# Compatibility condition for the Poisson equation in Lax-Milgram theory

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces

I am wondering how the compatibility condition for the Poisson equation influences the
Lax-Milgram setup. Consider the Poisson equation with Neumann boundary conditions

$$ -u'' = f$$
$$ u'(0) = u'(1) = 0$$

The corresponding variational formulation is

$$ B[u, v] = \int_0^1 u' v' dm = \int_0^1 fvdm = F[v] \quad (\forall v \in H^1(0,1))$$

which does not satisfy the requirements for the Lax-Milgram theorem as B is not coercive.
By plugging in the constant 1 function on $(0,1)$, we see that $f$ must fulfill the following compatibility condition

$$ 0 = B[u, \mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}] = \int_0^1 u' (\mathbb{1}_{(0,1)})' dm = B[u, \mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}] =  F[\mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}] = \int_0^1fdm.$$

Now, replacing the Hilbert space $H^1((0,1))$ by the subspace $H = \{v\in H^1((0,1))| \int_0^1vdm = 0\}$, the bilinear form B now becomes coercive because the Poincaré inequality holds on $H$. Further, $F$ is a continous linear form and the Lax-Milgram theorem gives us the existence of a unique solution for any $f\in L^2$. Am I missing something or did the compatibility condition just disappear by removing the non-zero constant functions from our Hilbert space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the variational formulation is
$$
B(u,v) = F(v) \quad \forall v\in H,
$$
you will get the same solution if you replace $f$ by $f+1$, for instance. This is the price to pay for existence and uniqueness.

Using Fredholm theory, one can prove existence of weak solutions  in $H^1$ if and only if $f$ satisfies the compatibility condition
$$
\int_\Omega f \ dx = 0.
$$